# Validate gradle task graph

Tags: gradle

I need to refactor and break up a very large plugin that belongs to someone else. One thing that i absolutely can not do is change the existing task graph. I am trying to add baseline unit tests right now that i can use to verify i don't change anything when i break this apart. Now plan A was to add the plugin task tree and pull a tree from testkit tests that compare the task trees with the expected. the problem is one of the task trees looks like this

```
:buildDocsHtml
+--- :installBuildRequirements
|    \--- :installSetupRequirements
|         \--- :installLinks
|              \--- :createVirtualEnvironment
|                   \--- :pinRequirements
\--- :installProject
     \--- :installTestRequirements
          \--- :installPythonRequirements
               \--- :installBuildRequirements
                    \--- :installSetupRequirements
                         \--- :installLinks
                              \--- :createVirtualEnvironment
                                   \--- :pinRequirements
```

Thats going to be a nightmare to try to compare as a string. Is there an easier way to pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt the [source code for the task tree plugin](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/dorongold/gradle/tasktree/TaskTreeTask.groovy) to produce a format that is better for diffing

Comment: I considered that.  But the problem is the plugin doesn't actually render the tree.  The tree rendering is done by an internal gradle class he shouldn't be calling to begin with.  And a look at the class, looks to me like it's part of a larger system.  I'd rather stay away from that if I can.  But if there's no other way, that's what I will end up doing

Comment: There's also the [gradle VisTEG plugin](https://github.com/mmalohlava/gradle-visteg). Perhaps you could compare the `.dot` files it produces?